# The application encountered an error while attempting to change the state of 'WindowsServer2008'

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I've had a Hyper-V running Windows Server 2008 for about two years. Today I did a Save on the VM in the Hyper-V Manager and then restarted my computer. When computer restarted I went to Start this VM and got the following error:

[Window Title]
 Virtual Machine Connection

[Main Instruction]
 The application encountered an error while attempting to change the state of 'WindowsServer2008'.

[Content]
 'WindowsServer2008' failed to restore.

Microsoft Video Monitor (Instance ID BA8735EF-E3A9-4F1B-BADD-DBF3A5909915): Failed to restore with Error 'Catastrophic failure'.

[Expanded Information]
 'WindowsServer2008' failed to restore. (Virtual machine ID 07307F40-CA38-4780-A62B-CD873410948D)

'WindowsServer2008' Microsoft Video Monitor (Instance ID BA8735EF-E3A9-4F1B-BADD-DBF3A5909915): Failed to restore with Error 'Catastrophic failure' (0x8000FFFF). (Virtual machine ID 07307F40-CA38-4780-A62B-CD873410948D)

===============

The Event Viewer had no additional error information and just repeated the above messages. I did not change any monitor or drivers on my system. I started up a different VM on my system that runs Win 8.1 and that came up with no problem.

What can I try to fix this?

Walter

Comment: Does a safe boot and repair ? Else check for a snapshot or backup

Answer (score 6):

The saved state is corrupted, in Hyper-V manager select the vm and delete saved state.

[image: Delete Saved State in Hyper-V manager]

More details:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2502233

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is no point in creating a new VM just to delete the saved state.

Comment: The above steps fixed a case for me using an Ubuntu VM on Windows 10 after (what I assume was) changes to displays and or power and or network status (i.e. moving my laptop around with the VM open)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and in my case the solution was very simple. My HDD (where the virtual disk was stored) was full and I had to delete some files to get enough space to be able to start the VM. The error message that I got was super unhelpful, I had to go to Event Viewer and find some error code 0x80070070, Google it and then finally I found that it had something to do with disk space. Hyper-V should be able to just tell me that...

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to fix this. Apparently the .vhdsk was still good just the saved state was bad. In the Hyper-V Manager I created a new VM and in the Wizard create process I chose the option to use an existing .vhdsk and pointed it at mine. I connected to it and all was fine! I lost any unsaved data in applications that were open but that's nothing to thinking I lost the entire VM.

Comment: If you were going to lose the unsaved data it would have been faster to simply do what Juan Blanco suggested and delete the saved state of the VM.